# NSBundle.allFrameworks doesn't return some of the frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, ios11, ios12

We are developing an SDK in Objective-C and as part of our service to our SDk consumers we have a tool that checks to see if all the required frameworks exist in the develop project.
In order for us to do so we use **NSBundle.allFrameworks** that should return all of the frameworks and we search for the required framework in the returned result.

We are seeing a weird behaviour with that call that changes between OS versions.
For example when we call **NSBundle.allFrameworks** on iOS the returned list doesn't contain some of the frameworks such as 
**MobileCoreServices, CoreGraphics, UIKit, SystemConfiguration**

If we run the same call on an iOS 11 device the only framework that is missing is **SystemConfiguration**.

Is anyone familiar with this behaviour?
We would really love to provide that functionality for our users

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1408056-allframeworks?language=objc), it returns:

> An array of all of the application’s bundles that represent frameworks. Only frameworks with one or more Objective-C classes in them are included.

And the **Discussion** section mentions that:

> The returned array includes frameworks that are linked into an application when the application is built and bundles for frameworks that have been dynamically created.

This means that frameworks with at least one Objective-C class, and that are bundled within the app/linked against the app, are shown.

e.g. If both the app and the bundled frameworks are not linking against a specific framework, it won't appear in the list.

Comment: Thanks Matteo
I read the docs as well and saw these definitions.
The weird part is that we have a test application that we created in order for us to test our SDK. When I connect an iPhone with OS 12 to my Mac and compile this app I get one set of frameworks and when I connect it to another device that is running OS 11 I get a different set of frameworks.
I didn't change the frameworks definitions between the two compilations.
That is why I was wondering if anyone knows what might be the reason for those frameworks to be left out of the frameworks list.

Comment: @Roi it could well be different `iOS` versions having different requirements in terms of framework linkage